# Soft Link redirection in linux

Tags: linux, symlink

I have created a soft link as follows:

```
/bip/etl>ln -s /bip/etl bipet
```

And now can see the soft link being created as well..

```
/bip/etl>ls -lrt |tail
-rw-rw-rw-    1 cdtbipx cduserg  24988174 Jun 19 19:17 227015716_WLR3PSTN_Filtered_06202016_5of6.csv.gz.gpg
-rw-rw-rw-    1 cdtbipx cduserg  23857587 Jun 19 19:17 227015716_WLR3PSTN_Filtered_06202016_6of6.csv.gz.gpg
drwxrwxrwx 1082 prod    release     61440 Jul  3 02:51 WSC
drwxrwxrwx    5 oracle  oinstall     4096 Jul  4 01:22 dsl
lrwxrwxrwx    1 cdtbipx cduserg         8 Jul  4 08:43 bipet -> /bip/etl
```

However, I cannot refer to the soft link `bipet` while I try to search a specific file in the concerned folder.

```
ls -lrt /bipetl/227015716_WLR3PSTN_Filtered_06202016_6of6.csv.gz.gpg
ls: /bipetl/227015716_WLR3PSTN_Filtered_06202016_6of6.csv.gz.gpg: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: ls -lrt /bipetl/ => ls -lrt /bipet/, is this wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You created a link `bipet` in directory `/bip/etl` (current working directory when you did `ln`).

You you should do:

```
ls -lrt /bip/etl/bipetl/227015716_WLR3PSTN_Filtered_06202016_6of6.csv.gz.gpg
```

Or create the link using (assuming you have privileges to write to the `/`):

```
ln -s /bip/etl /bipet
```

And then you can do:

```
ls -lrt /bipetl/227015716_WLR3PSTN_Filtered_06202016_6of6.csv.gz.gpg
```